# CakePHP 3: Manually update 'created' timestamp field

Tags: cakephp, orm, timestamp, behavior, cakephp-3.x

The TimeStamp behavior auto-populates **created** and **modified** fields. Is there a way to override the created field (say, I'm importing users from an external system and would like to preserve the creation timestamps)?

I could not find any useful information on this in the [TimeStamp documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/timestamp.html).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp behavior only populates/updates these fields [**if they're not already dirty**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.7.0/src/ORM/Behavior/TimestampBehavior.php#L197-L199).

You can simply populate them with your desired values (or mark them as dirty if you want to preserve existing values), and the behavior won't touch them.

Comment: One can also [remove the behavior](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors.html#removing-loaded-behaviors),  if that's more appropriate.